# Which executable is run by DOS/CMD if multiple results are returned by 'where'?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I'm running Win10, with Cygwin, Git for Windows and Ubuntu WSL installed.
Running these commands in DOS and Powershell returns the following results:

```bash
# DOS
C:\>where grep
C:\cygwin64\bin\grep.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe

# DOS
C:\>which grep
/usr/bin/grep

# Powershell
C:\> gcm grep*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     grep.exe                                           0.0.0.0    C:\cygwin64\bin\grep.exe
Application     grep.exe                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe
```

Now when I run this, which one of the above actually runs?

```bash
# DOS / Powershell
C:\>grep ... ---> ?
```

Is it run in the order they appear here, or are listed in PATH environment variable? Or another order (which one)?

Comment: cmd isn't DOS. [They're very different shells](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386). Don't tag DOS here

Comment: whichever is in the PATH environment. As noted above, DOS isn't cmd. MS-DOS was the entirety of the OS back in the day; hence the name.

Comment: @phuclv I knew what DOS stands for and am old enough to have used DOS as the OS, but I definitely did not realize the differences in your link (command.com - vs cmd), thank you for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**Terminology** aside: I assume you mean **[`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)** aka the **Command Prompt**, the command shell of modern Windows versions, not the *long-obsolete **[(MS-)DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS)*** and its `command.com` counterpart.</sup>

> Is it run in the order they appear here, or are listed in PATH environment variable? Or another order (which one)?

**Yes, the *first* executable whose path is listed in the results from your calls is the one that will be called if you submit `grep`**, i.e. a mere file *name*, as a command.

However, note that you should have called `gcm grep`, not `gcm grep*`, in which case you'd have received only *one* result, because [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) (whose built-in alias is `gcm`), when given a *literal* name (rather than a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expression), only returns the *effective* form / path of that command by default, as the Unix `which` utility does.

Both `Get-Command` and `which` require *opt-in* if you want to know *all* forms / paths of a given name, namely via `-All` and `-a`, respectively, in which case they are listed in descending order of precedence, i.e. with the *effective* one printing first.

`where.exe`, by contrast, *invariably* prints *all* paths, in descending order of precedence.

**Among *external programs*** - which are the only command form considered by `which` and `where.exe` - **it is the order in which directories are listed in the `PATH` environment variable that determines precedence**: an executable with a given name is looked for sequentially in the directories listed, and the first one found is the effective one.

On Windows, if no file-name extension is given, it is the extensions listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable that are applied in sequence to look for a complete file name, so that `grep` finds `grep.exe`, for instance.

`Get-Command` by default additionally looks for *PowerShell-specific* command forms, in the form of aliases, functions, cmdlets, as well as `.ps1` script files, in that order, before considering external programs.
You can limit lookups to external programs with `-Type Application`, but note that *on invocation* you may have to *include the filename extension* in order to bypass another command form that would otherwise take precedence.
For instance, `where` would find / invoke the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlet* (one of whose built-in aliases is `where`), whereas `where.exe` would find / invoke the *external program*.
On Unix-like platforms, where external programs typically don't have extensions, more work is needed on invocation; e.g., to invoke a hypothetical `where` program without accidentally invoking the `Where-Object` cmdlet, you'd have to use 
`& (Get-Command -Type Application where)`

Note that the same applies in principle to `cmd.exe` and POSIX-compatible shells: they too have *internal* commands that can shadow external programs of the same name (e.g., `dir` in `cmd.exe`, and `printf` in Bash); in `cmd.exe`, you can again use the executable's file-name extension to ensure that the external program is targeted; in POSIX-compatible shells, you can call via `$(which printf)`, for instance.

In short: Only `Get-Command` in PowerShell gives you the *full* picture with respect to what a command a given name will actually invoke; the `where.exe` and `which` utilities - of necessity - are limited to *external programs*.

Finally, as Mofi notes, there is an important difference between `cmd.exe` on the one hand and PowerShell and POSIX-compatible shells on the other:

- Only `cmd.exe` allows you to execute an external program located in the *current* directory by name only.
- By security-minded design, PowerShell and POSIX-compatible shells do *not* support that, and require a *path* to refer to the program in this case; in the simplest form: `.\foo.exe` / `./foo`.
- `where.exe` *does* report executables in the *current* directory, so if you call it from PowerShell, you may get a false positive; that said, given the availability of the more flexible `Get-Command` cmdlet, there's no good reason to call `where.exe` from PowerShell.